# $\exists x \forall y (P(y) \implies Q(x))$ and $\forall y P(y) \implies \exists x Q(x)$ are not logically equivalent

Tags: logic

I am trying to show that the following are not logically equivalent (according to a practice question)

$\exists x \forall y (P(y) \implies Q(x))$ and $\forall y P(y) \implies \exists x Q(x)$

In the first case I am trying to find some kind of statement where $x,y$ are integers (something like $P(x)$ is the is even predicate and $Q(x)$ is odd predicate, or maybe that $Q(x)$ implies $x$ divides $y$).

I am imagining I need a scenario where one statement is True implies False, and the other is True, for the same values of $x,y$.

If $\forall y P(y)$ is false, then both implications will be true, so suppose that $\forall y$ P(y) is true. I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Hints/Clarifications appreciated.

Comment: why are both sides true when $\forall y P(y)$ is false?

Comment: @supinf I meant both implications.

Comment: I still do not understand it.

Comment: @supinf for the statement on the right, it would imply False -> Something is True.
For the first statement, it would be exists an x, for all y (P(y)=False -> Q(x)) which is also true? Maybe I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint 1**:

Your statement, that the first statement is true if $\forall y P(y)$ is false,
was a mistake.
In your comment it seems like you thought that
if $\forall yP(y)$ does not hold, then $P(y)$ is always false.
It can also happen that $P(y)$ is false for some $y$ and true for some $y$.

You actually should assume, that $\forall y P(y)$ is false,
but there is an $y$ such that $P(y)$ is true.

**hint 2**:

Consider the two cases for $\exists x Q(x)$.
What happens if it is false? what if it is true?

Comment: I have added my own overall answer, if you could check its correctness that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With false and true respectively $0$ and $1$, the statements are$$\max_yP(y)\le\max_xQ(x)$$ and$$\min_yP(y)=1\implies\max_xQ(x)=1.$$These statements differ in truth value if$$\min_yP(y)=0,\,\max_yP(y)=1,\,\max_xQ(x)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

As per supinf's hints. How about this argument:

Suppose that $\exists y$ such that $P(y)$ is true, but $\forall y P(y)$ is false. Also suppose that $Q(x)$ is false for any $x$.

Then the first logical statement is false since for such a $y$ where $P(y)$ is true, we would have there exists an $x$ such that $P(y) \implies Q(x)$ is true, which is false, and so the overall statement is false.

For the second statement, since the premise $\forall y P(y)$ is false, then the statement is vacuously true. Hence the statements aren't equivalent.

Comment: This is correct. Alternatively, you could also use concrete statements for $P$ and $Q$ to show that the implications are not equivalent.